# Reduce size/number of files being downloaded from EXTJS app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I used Sencha CMD to build an app and want to ensure that I'm only downloading what is required for the app to run.  I have read some places that the way to do this is by using the Required [] clause to only include the required classes, however I don't think I understand this clearly.  For example I have a page that has an {xtype: 'grid'} within it, but I haven't put Requires : [ 'Ext.grid.Panel' ], yet it still displays properly.  In my mind if I haven't included the requires, and CMD is doing what I think it should, this page should fail to load because Ext.grid.Panel wasn't included.  The fact that it's working is making me think that CMD is automatically including it for me, but what else is it automatically including and potentially bloating the download?  How can I ensure that I'm only downloading what's required for the app to run?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem.  I was developing my app on the same server that I'm serving it from, and when I was running "sencha app build production", it's putting all of the "build" files into a separate directory.  I was assuming the microloader/bootstrap process was then going to look in that directory but I guess that's not how it works.  I had to then copy those "build" files to a new directory and include my index.html and bootstrap.js in the new directory and then it appears to work, only loading the required files.  It's certainly not clear anywhere that this is what's required.  Hopefully this will help anyone else having the same issue.